# Improving loop in loops with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy arrays aside from pandas for speed purposes. However, I am unable to advance my codes using broadcasting, indexing etc. Instead, I am using loop in loops as below. It is working but seems so ugly and inefficient to me.

Basically what I am doing is, I am trying to imitate groupby of pandas at the step `mydata[mydata[:,1]==i]`. You may consider it as a firm id number. Then with respect to the **lookup** data, I am checking if it is inside the selected firm or not at the step `all(np.isin(lookup[u],d[:,3]))`. But as I denoted at the beginning, I feel so uncomfortable about this.

```
out = []
for i in np.unique(mydata[:,1]):
    d = mydata[mydata[:,1]==i]
    
    for u in range(0,len(lookup)):
        control = all(np.isin(lookup[u],d[:,3]))
        if(control):
            out.append(d[np.isin(d[:,3],lookup[u])])
```

It takes about 0.27 seconds. However there must exist some clever alternatives.

I also tried Numba `jit()` but it does not work.

Could anyone help me about that?

Thanks in advance!

**Fake Data:**

```
a = np.repeat(np.arange(100)+5000, np.random.randint(50, 100, 100))
b =  np.random.randint(100,200,len(a))
c = np.random.randint(10,70,len(a))
index =  np.arange(len(a))
mydata = np.vstack((index,a, b,c)).T

lookup = []
for i in range(0,60):
    lookup.append(np.random.randint(10,70,np.random.randint(3,6,1) ))
```

Comment: This is not the typical problem that `broadcasting` and `indexing` helps with.  For one thing you are using `unique`, which under the covers uses `sort` to bring like values together.  And you are doing that `if` test inside the inner loop.  `numpy` doesn't have much in the way of `grouping` tools.  Python `itertools` and `pandas` have better for grouping.  Or if you really need speed, bite-the-bullet and use `numba` or `cython`.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems getting the goal of your Program, but I got a decent performance improvement, by refactoring your second for loop. I was able to compress your code to 3 or 4 lines.

```python
f = (
    lambda lookup: out1.append(d[np.isin(d[:, 3], lookup)])
    if all(np.isin(lookup, d[:, 3]))
    else None
)
out = []
for i in np.unique(mydata[:, 1]):
    d = mydata[mydata[:, 1] == i]
    list(map(f, lookups))
```

This resolves to the same output list you received previously and the code runs almost twice as quick (at least on my machine).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Upvoted. But unfortunately in my computer it gives almost the same elapsed time.